# Regular expression in .htaccess (optional subdirectory)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Having some trouble with regular expressions in my .htaccess file.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?(.*) $2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/? page.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

The first rule is supposed to remove an optional "section" part from the path, so both of these:

```
/section-2/news.php?id=73
/news.php?id=73
```

leads to

```
/news.php?id=73
```

And that works fine.

The second rule is supposed to send these kinds of paths:

```
/section-2/page/page-title
/page/page-title
```

to:

```
/page.php?id=page-title
```

But the first RewriteRule is obviously removing /page/ from the paths that doesn't have a "section" and thus, the second rule doesn't apply.

Any suggestions on how to solve this? How do I make the first rule NOT match if the first part is /page/?

Answer (score 0):

You could define the word "section" within the pattern?

```
RewriteRule ^(section[a-z0-9\-_]+)/?(.*) $2 [NC]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't specify: "section" could be any word. "Section" was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

After even more googling and trial and error, I came up with this for the first rule, which excludes paths beginning with page/.

```
RewriteRule ^((?!page/)[a-z0-9\-_]+)/?(.*) $2 [NC]
```

This seems to work but if anyone comes across this question and has any suggestions on how to improve or optimize these rules, please share them!